# Why the amstools doesn't work here?

Tags: lyx, amsthm, hebrew

Look at this file, when I compile it at LyX it says that:
[image]

And here is the file:

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.3.0 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[a4paper,english,hebrew]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{\protect\definitionname}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Yehuda CLM}
\AtBeginDocument{
\renewcommand\footnoterule{%
  \kern -3pt
  \hbox to \textwidth{\hfill\vrule height 0.4pt width .4\textwidth}
  \kern 2.6pt
}}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\color{blue}\normalfont\bfseries,
  bodyfont=\color{red}\normalfont\itshape,
]{colored}

\declaretheorem[
  style=colored,
  name=Definition,
]{defn}

\makeatother

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\definitionname}{Definition}}
\addto\captionshebrew{\renewcommand{\definitionname}{הגדרה}}
\providecommand{\definitionname}{הגדרה}

\begin{document}

\begin{defn}
אבג
\end{defn}

\end{document}
```

Can you explain me why is this and how can I fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: You are doing both `\newtheorem{defn}{...}` and `\declaretheorem[...]{defn}`.

Comment: @campa how can I fix it?

Comment: LyX put it for me I think...

Comment: @heblyx  can you please post a bug report on https://www.lyx.org/trac with a minimal example that doesn't use custom ERT or a LaTeX preamble? We should be able to fix this bug.

Comment: @scottkosty - https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/11268

Comment: @heblyx thanks for opening that. You might want to instead make your own module. For example you can call the environment "definition_heblyx", so it doesn't interfere with environments already defined. Note that LyX modules are just text files. For example, find the file "theorems-ams.inc" on your computer and study that. Also read the Help > Customization manual.