# How to change the style of a theorem at LyX?

Tags: lyx, theorems, amsthm, hebrew

As a continue to this question - [Why the amstools doesn't work here?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448301/why-the-amstools-doesnt-work-here?noredirect=1#comment1126852_448301) - I think to ask it from a different view:
[image]
I'm using this at Lyx and I want to change the style of the theorems like here: 
[How to produce theorems in which the color of heading and body of the theorem my differ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283578/how-to-produce-theorems-in-which-the-color-of-heading-and-body-of-the-theorem-my)

The first two answers doesn't work at all, and make problems, like here: [Why the amstools doesn't work here?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448301/why-the-amstools-doesnt-work-here?noredirect=1#comment1126852_448301) (same question above)

So my questions is: There is a way to change the style of theorems and things like that **without** creating new ones? Because, as I saw at the answers - the just redesign the style and don't create a new object.
(remember that I'm using LyX...)

Thank you!!

```
% Preview source code
%% LyX 2.3.0 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[a4paper,english,hebrew]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\theoremstyle{plain}
    \ifx\thechapter\undefined
        \newtheorem{thm}{\protect\theoremname}
      \else
      \newtheorem{thm}{\protect\theoremname}[chapter]
    \fi

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Yehuda CLM}
\AtBeginDocument{
\renewcommand\footnoterule{%
  \kern -3pt
  \hbox to \textwidth{\hfill\vrule height 0.4pt width .4\textwidth}
  \kern 2.6pt
}}
% declare a new theorem style
\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}%
{3pt}% Space above
{3pt}% Space below 
{\itshape\color{red}}% Body font
{}% Indent amount
{\bfseries\color{blue}}% Theorem head font
{.}% Punctuation after theorem head
{.5em}% Space after theorem head 
{}% Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)

% use the new theorem style
\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\makeatother

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\theoremname}{Theorem}}
\addto\captionshebrew{\renewcommand{\theoremname}{משפט}}
\providecommand{\theoremname}{משפט}

\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
שלום
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello @heblyx, I recently wrote a latex package and a lyx module accompany to it to solve this problem in lyx. This module will let you customize the theorem format, numbering etc., with the keys available at the thmtools package, within the lyx document. If you would like, reach me by mail (see my profile) for more details.